# Citrus simulator not getting started in browser

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, server, simulator, citrus-framework

I am trying to do the below linked Citrus Simulator sample and when I try to run the http://localhost:8080 or http://localhost:8080/services/rest/ as mentioned in the page to start my simulator, it throws This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect.

Note: There is no proxy I am using in my browser. It is normal.

Could somebody please help me start the citrus simulator by running the below springboot project.
https://github.com/citrusframework/citrus-simulator-demo

link: https://citrusframework.org/news/2017/09/21/introducing-citrus-simulator/

Answer (score 0):

Have you executed the steps described in [citrus-simulator-demo#build-and-run](https://github.com/citrusframework/citrus-simulator-demo#build-and-run)? You need to build and run the simulator locally in order to access the UI in the browser. If you see errors while building and running the simulator it will not work until this has been fixed on your local environment.